# Why is CloudFront not forwarding my Content-Type header for an svg served from S3?

Tags: svg, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to load a page from CloudFront, and the svg is showing up as a missing image.

When I look into the response headers, I see that when I load the S3 bucket directly, the response contains the proper content type:  image/svg+xml

```
$ curl -I https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pages.ivizone.com/1/19/1509969889/images/kenzo-logo-v2.svg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: k3+bRpJLp+avBaUWO4VSgB+Djxb+nebnGJs3u6kQ0rMeX95h3XeLHA03XYaWioat+JqNG6x61x8=
x-amz-request-id: 43D8ED0E9EB4490C
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 15:06:13 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 14:08:00 GMT
ETag: "4b8f9e399ec9bc166040a2641cf33fb3"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Length: 9484
Server: AmazonS3
```

However when I pass through CloudFront, the header is missing:

```
$ curl -I https://pages.ivizone.com/1/19/1509969889/images/kenzo-logo-v2.svg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 9484
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 14:01:01 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 12:04:52 GMT
ETag: "4b8f9e399ec9bc166040a2641cf33fb3"
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 ed9babcd75a95b818a6df1694ba95225.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: va4AIkAzw7-tNZ-qQo4KA_czM29tFQAzmNH_P0wjYd_TiboSBAyohA==
```

As a result, this is causing problems rendering my images.

Would anyone know why Cloudfront strips the header, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, It looks like I screwed up somewhere.  When uploading the svg image to S3, I had to add the content type string to the S3 Object metadata:

```
"image/svg+xml"
```

(no spaces)

Once I added this on upload, the image was served properly.

S3 doesn't send a content-type header by default, so my browser probably interpreted the svg in an incorrect format.   By specifying the header, it knew how to handle it